# How to display Bootstrap Offcanvas inside a Modal

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5, bootstrap5-modal

Is it possible to display Bootstrap [Offcanvas](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/offcanvas/) inside a [Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#fullscreen-modal)?

Here is my code:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">Modal 1</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Show a "Offcanvas right" by clicking the button below.
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasRight" aria-controls="offcanvasRight">Toggle right offcanvas</button>
      </div>
      <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasRight" aria-labelledby="offcanvasRightLabel">
  <div class="offcanvas-header">
    <h5 id="offcanvasRightLabel">Offcanvas right</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="offcanvas-body">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        

modal footer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle2" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel2" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalToggleLabel2">Modal 2</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Hide this modal and show the first with the button below.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Back to first</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModalToggle" role="button">Open first modal</a>
```

Comment: Offcanvas uses position fixed and is intended as a top level page component.  You would need to develop a custom Offcanvas solution to use it as a child component within a modal.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
  <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title> Museum of Candy </title>
    
    <style>
    
    .modal-content {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .modal-content .offcanvas {
        position: absolute;
    }

    </style>
</head>
 
<body>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">Modal 1</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Show a "Offcanvas right" by clicking the button below.
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasRight" aria-controls="offcanvasRight">Toggle right offcanvas</button>
      </div>
      <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasRight" aria-labelledby="offcanvasRightLabel">
  <div class="offcanvas-header">
    <h5 id="offcanvasRightLabel">Offcanvas right</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="offcanvas-body">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        

modal footer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle2" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel2" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalToggleLabel2">Modal 2</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Hide this modal and show the first with the button below.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Back to first</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModalToggle" role="button">Open first modal</a>
<!-- This is the JS section that's not working: -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This does not work, though it is a good start.

Comment: Please add this inside your head tag: 

 <style>
 
 .modal-content {
    overflow: hidden;
 }

 .modal-content .offcanvas {
  position: absolute;
 }

 </style>

Comment: I checked and it works

Comment: I have added the full html, you can check it

Comment: Sorry, but not working.  See this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/koyg1xnd/) of your code.